# Dart Editor: original example web app (using polymer) : compiling error

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I have installed version:
Dart Editor version 1.1.3.release (STABLE)
Dart SDK version 1.1.3
I created a new web application using the libraries of polymer. The application is the original example that brings the editor: clickcounter. I have not added or removed anything. The application works fine without error. But when trying to compile, very many errors arise. I followed the recommendations given in dartlang.org.
   For that reason not compile the original example that brings the editor? Anyone have a clue?
You can try it yourself.
This is the list of errors shown in OUTPUT:

```
--- 19-feb-2014 7:23:26 Running dart2js... ---
E:\dart\dart-sdk\bin\dart2js.bat --out=E:\Proyectos DART\carreta\PruebaPolymer\build.dart.js E:\Proyectos DART\carreta\PruebaPolymer\build.dart
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/builder.dart:85:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
       ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/linter.dart:11:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
       ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/barback/src/asset.dart:8:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
       ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/barback/src/file_pool.dart:9:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
       ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:13:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
       ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/yaml/src/parser.dart:5:9: Warning: Duplicated library name 'parser'.
library parser;
        ^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/html5lib/parser.dart:16:9: Warning: Duplicated library name 'parser'.
library parser;
        ^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/yaml/src/utils.dart:5:9: Warning: Duplicated library name 'utils'.
library utils;
        ^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/html5lib/src/utils.dart:2:9: Warning: Duplicated library name 'utils'.
library utils;
        ^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:221:19: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Directory'.
    var dir = new Directory(options.outDir);
                  ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:276:22: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Link'.
      var link = new Link(linkPath);
                     ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:278:26: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Platform'.
        var targetPath = Platform.operatingSystem == 'windows'
                         ^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:332:32: Warning: Cannot resolve 'File'.
  return asset.read().pipe(new File(filepath).openWrite());
                               ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:310:7: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Directory'.
  new Directory(dirpath).createSync(recursive: true);
      ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:326:14: Warning: Cannot resolve 'File'.
  return new File(inpath).openRead().pipe(new File(outpath).openWrite());
             ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:326:47: Warning: Cannot resolve 'File'.
  return new File(inpath).openRead().pipe(new File(outpath).openWrite());
                                              ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:131:17: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Directory'.
  var dir = new Directory(path.join(packageDir, subDir));
                ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:134:26: Warning: Cannot resolve type 'File'.
      .where((f) => f is File)
                         ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:195:5: Warning: Cannot resolve 'exit'.
    exit(1);
    ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:201:7: Warning: Cannot resolve 'exit'.
      exit(1);
      ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:366:19: Warning: Cannot resolve 'stdioType'.
  var useColors = stdioType(stdout) == StdioType.TERMINAL;
                  ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:366:29: Warning: Cannot resolve 'stdout'.
  var useColors = stdioType(stdout) == StdioType.TERMINAL;
                            ^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:366:40: Warning: Cannot resolve 'StdioType'.
  var useColors = stdioType(stdout) == StdioType.TERMINAL;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/barback/src/asset.dart:27:38: Warning: Cannot resolve type 'File'.
  factory Asset.fromFile(AssetId id, File file) =>
                                     ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/barback/src/file_pool.dart:38:30: Warning: Cannot resolve 'File'.
      return Chain.track(new File(path).openRead()).transform(
                             ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/barback/src/file_pool.dart:58:23: Warning: Cannot resolve 'BytesBuilder'.
    var builder = new BytesBuilder();
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:99:18: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Platform'.
  var dartExec = Platform.executable;
                 ^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:102:31: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Platform'.
  var pub = path.join(sdkDir, Platform.isWindows ? 'pub.bat' : 'pub');
                              ^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:103:16: Warning: Cannot resolve 'Process'.
  var result = Process.runSync(pub, ['list-package-dirs']);
               ^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:108:5: Warning: Cannot resolve 'exit'.
    exit(result.exitCode);
    ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/src/build/runner.dart:82:21: Warning: Cannot resolve 'File'.
  var pubspec = new File(
                    ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/builder.dart:323:5: Warning: Cannot resolve 'exit'.
    exit(1);
    ^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/carreta/PruebaPolymer/packages/polymer/builder.dart:328:5: Warning: Cannot resolve 'exit'.
    exit(0);
    ^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

I can not find the error. An idea??

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and worked without any errors and warnings.
Maybe a problem with your packages (dependencies).
Can you try `pub get` and `pub upgrade` (from the context menu on `pubspec.yaml`) and post the output if this shows errors.

Comment: Ok: go it :
--- 19-feb-2014 15:28:35 Running pub get ... ---
Resolving dependencies.......
Got dependencies!

Comment: Pub Upgrade--- 19-feb-2014 15:29:41 Running pub upgrade ... ---
Resolving dependencies........................
  analyzer 0.10.5 (9 newer versions available)
  args 0.9.0 (2 newer versions available)
  barback 0.11.0+3
  browser 0.9.1
  collection 0.9.1
  custom_element 0.9.1+2 (1 newer version available)
  html5lib 0.9.1
  html_import 0.9.0
  logging 0.9.1+1
  mutation_observer 0.9.0
  observe 0.9.3
  path 1.0.0
  polymer 0.9.5
  polymer_expressions 0.9.1
  shadow_dom 0.9.1 (1 newer version available)
  source_maps 0.9.0
  stack_trace 0.9.1

Comment: ontinue pub upgrade:  template_binding 0.9.1
  unmodifiable_collection 0.9.2+1
  utf 0.9.0
  yaml 0.9.0
No dependencies changed.

Comment: Pub Build:--- 19-feb-2014 15:31:40 Running pub build ... ---
Building PruebaPolymer.....
[Warning from Dart2JS on PruebaPolymer|web/pruebapolymer.html_bootstrap.dart]:[Dart2JS on PruebaPolymer|web/pruebapolymer.html_bootstrap.dart]:


[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:14.080019 to compile PruebaPolymer|web/pruebapolymer.html_bootstrap.dart.
Built 23 files!

Comment: No depencies updated but successfully built?
Seems it was a problem with the package symlinks. So the problem is solved then?

Comment: no, I can`t compiling to js; have errors, de same mistakes.

Comment: Your comment contained `Built 23 files!` which is an indication that build was successful. How do you build? `pub build` from the package directory?

Comment: Anything still not working then? (pub build is compiling to JS - look into build/web directory to find the JS output)

Comment: There are a lot of warnings, the Dart team is working on improving this. But when at the end the output is "Built xx files!" instead of "Build failed" it's fine.

Comment: This is the first two errors:
--- 20-feb-2014 10:00:17 Running dart2js... ---
E:\dart\dart-sdk\bin\dart2js.bat --out=E:\Proyectos DART\Componentes\Carrusel\build.dart.js E:\Proyectos DART\Componentes\Carrusel\build.dart
/E:/Proyectos DART/Componentes/Carrusel/packages/polymer/builder.dart:85:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
       ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/Proyectos DART/Componentes/Carrusel/packages/polymer/src/build/linter.dart:11:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
       ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: There is some trick involved to make some libraries usable in both the browser and on the server. 'dart:io' **can't be loaded in the browser**. but it's usually used on the server so there is probably some dependency. You can ignore this error.